# Getting WrappedAttributeError when logged into website with djangorestframework freshly installed

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a website that has a user login function and works fine. I had to install django rest framework and followed the very basic instructions on the first page. Everything seems fine and rest framework works fine, but as soon as I log into my django and go back to rest framework it breaks with this error:

```
WrappedAttributeError at /rest-api/
'CSRFCheck' object has no attribute 'process_request'
```

I have no idea why this happens or what it means. Searching didn't help.

Edit: Exception location:

```
python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/authentication.py in enforce_csrf, line 140
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have created an issue to report this : https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/6305

You can see a fix here if you need a patch rapidly : https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/pull/6306/files

## More details

In the release of Django Rest Framework 3.9 a new function call was introduced in the authentication process:

```
check = CSRFCheck()
check.process_request(request)
```

CSRFCheck is a class imported directly from Django. The process_request method of the CSRFCheck class was only added in the Django 1.11.6 version (and keeped after that). Therefore the release 3.9.0 of Django Rest Framework is not fully compatible with Django 1.11.x but only with 1.11.6 and upwards. Many solutions exists to this issue:

- Upgrade to Django 1.11.6 or upward if possible
- Fork Django Rest Framework and include the following patch in the enforce_csrf method of the SessionAuthentication class (rest_framework/authentication.py):

  ```
  from django import VERSION as django_version

  if tuple(django_version[:3]) < (1, 11, 6):
      csrf_token = check._get_token(request)
      if csrf_token is not None:
          request.META['CSRF_COOKIE'] = csrf_token
  else:
      check.process_request(request)
  ```

This patch will work for any version of Django from 1.11.x and upward (at least Django 2.0 and 2.1).

Hopefully my patch will be merged and release in version 3.9.1 of Django Rest Framework. Also keep in mind that version 3.9.0 is probably one of the last release to support Django 1.11.

Comment: From review: Hi @Anto, could you please add more detail to your answer? So that even if the link breaks your answer is still valid. Thanks!

Comment: Well that worked! Thanks. Can you also give an ELI5 on this issue?

Comment: @toti08 I am new to SO so please forgive me. I have added more details, does it sounds better ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems really similar to [this issue](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/6088) that was fixed and in the 3.8.2 release of DRF.

These are the things I would try:

1. Make sure your Django is updated to at least 1.11 and DRF is updated to at least 3.8.2.
2. Make sure you added 'rest_framework' to *the bottom* of your `INSTALLED_APPS`. This is easy to miss in the installation tutorial.
3. Make sure your `MIDDLEWARE` in `settings.py` is relatively untouched, if this is a new project. At least make sure `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` is there and if there is any non-Django middleware above it, try moving it as far down as possible.

If none of this works, you can try truncating your `django_session` table, assuming you are using session authentication. I don't think this will help, but it's worth trying.

Comment: 1. Already 1.11 and latest DRF 3.9.0.
2. Already there
3. Done. No effect.